# What is the best way to validate that all values in a dictionary adhere to a JSON schema?

Tags: jsonschema

I want to validate that all `values` in a dictionary adhere to a schema while the `keys` can be whatever. Is there a better way to do this than just using a pattern that matches everything:

```json
"foo": {
    "type": "object",
    "patternProperties": {
        "^.*$": {
            "$ref": "#/$defs/bar"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `patternProperties` like you're doing is that best way, although you can simplify the regex to an empty string because regexes aren't implicitly anchored in JSON Schema.

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "patternProperties": {
    "": { "$ref": "#/$defs/bar" }
  }
}
```

The other option is to use `additionalProperties`, which is less verbose, but can lead to bugs.

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": { "$ref": "#/$defs/bar" }
}
```

The problem with this is that it's only accidentally the behavior you really want. What you want is to validate *all* properties against this schema. `additionalProperties` validates only the properties that aren't declared with `properties` or `patternProperties`. If later someone wants to add an additional constraint to a specific property and adds `properties`, they're going to break this schema unless they rewrite the `additionalProperties` using `patternProperties`.

It's one of those small things that's an unlikely to occur, but when it does, it's been known to be a source of bugs.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the `additionalProperties` keyword where you can also set a schema. More details [here](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#additional-properties)

Using `patternProperties`, the validator needs to run a RegExp check for each property which takes time.